# Should I use bold fonts to highlight particular words in SOP?

Tags: statement-of-purpose, formatting

Is it odd to use bold fonts to highlight particular important words in your SOP, such as the name of Professors I am interested to work with, or the name of a Lab? I have seen someone do this to highlight the Professor he is keen on working with. I am curious if this is an acceptable practice.

Example:

At Rice University, the works of **Dr. Gerard Fuller** are well suited to my research experience and goals.

Comment: Some university applications only allow plaintext, so any formatting like boldface would not work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am curious about the cases where the universities ask you to upload a PDF file of the SOP.

Comment: Alright, why not extend this line of reasoning to include hyperlinks, pictures, and video? Wouldn’t a multimedia SOP > text SOP?

Comment: Let me reframe that, another approach to your question is, “what value would boldfacing be compared to its absence?” The subject is clear in the sentence, the reason is also clear. When one **bolds** something, it draws the reader’s attention to it. Like **WARNING** smoking is hazardous to your health. So if you bold a professors name, what additional meaning does it confer to the reader?

Comment: I think using boldface is overkill. You can reserve something more discrete (say, italics) for translation of a foreign term or the definition of some very specific and technical term of your research.

Answer (score 5):

You are overthinking this. It's not going to make a difference whether or not you boldface names or other parts. Focus on the *content* of your statement, instead of spending your mental energy on issues such as boldfacing some text.

Comment: Cannot agree with this enough. The essay is an important part of the application and one should worry about selling themselves as high as they can.

Comment: Thanks for putting things in perspective. Your answer makes sense.